# HttpWebRequest response is always text/html when calling cross domain URL

Tags: c#, rest, cross-domain

I am using HttpWebRequest to get json result from a cross domain (https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post/oembed.json/?url=posturl). I have set ContentType and Accept to application/json, but I always get a text/html response. Expected result is JSON.

```
string result = string.Empty;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post/oembed.json/?url=xxxxxx");

request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";                

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `request.Method` to GET?

Comment: @swatsonpicken tried but same result as html

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17002205 to edit/update your question to add mention of the HTTP status code of the response. What’s most likely happening is that the response to your request is not a 200 OK but instead a 4xx or 5xx error message—in which case the response body would be an HTML error page instead of the expected JSON you’d get if the request were successful.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Response Status is OK. When i copy paste the same url in browser result is JSON

Comment: OK, then my next suggestion it look at the response body to see what it contains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you also need to set a browser agent in your request to get the expected results and not the embedded HTML from Facebook.

Something like:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

Comment: It is working fine.Thank You.Will it work in all browsers including ipad

Comment: It does not matter what browser anyone uses on your page as this is used in the server-side of things. I'm guessing Facebook is validating the user agent in their responses to prevent bots and spiders.

Comment: Thank You for your answer